# Using FileReader API inside a Vue.js component method

Tags: javascript, events, vue.js, filereader

I am developing a file picker with Vue.js. I want to show selected file previews.
I use [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to achieve this. I read the user selected files as data urls with `readAsDataURL` method of the `FileReader` object.

However I get an error message saying `reader.onload` is not a function like:

```
Uncaught TypeError: reader.onload is not a function
    at VueComponent.handleFileChanges
```

It may be the reader is not defined, following the FileReader undefined error I have mentioned above.

How I try to do do this is as follows:

```
handleFileChanges (e) {
    var reader = new window.FileReader() // if window is not used it says File READER is not defined
                reader.onload(function (event) {
                  // dispatch fileAttached to state UI postEditor with event.target.result as read dataURL
                  let imageDataURL = event.target.result
                  this.$store.dispatch('attachedFile', imageDataURL) // or previewFile
                })
                reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[i])
}
```

What is the point I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well as error says, and It's correct, It's not a function.Basically `onload` is event handler/property that is attached on newly constructed `FileReader` object and since It's not a function, It doesn't accept the any callback.

Use it like this:

```
handleFileChanges (e) {
    var reader = new window.FileReader() // if window is not used it says File READER is not defined
                reader.onload = function (event) {
                  // dispatch fileAttached to state UI postEditor with event.target.result as read dataURL
                  let imageDataURL = event.target.result
                  this.$store.dispatch('attachedFile', imageDataURL) // or previewFile
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[i])
}
```

Also make sure that `this` at `this.$store.dispatch` is bounded to correct context.

Answer (score 1):

Because [onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload) is a property, you should set (modify) it as a callback. But while `FileReader` inherits from `EventTarget`, all events (onload, onabort etc.) could be used with `addEventListener`. So in any case that you need to pass a callback as an event handler for on-load you might consider to use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

```
// method 1
reader.onload = function (e) { ...
// method 2
reader.addEventListener("onload", function (e) { ...
```